# In NP do we use "the" after "between"?

Tags: usage, determiners

Which example is correct?

> The gaps between platform and train are dangerous.

or

> The gaps between **the** platform and train are dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule that governs constructions such as these.

A sign on the platform might read: **Gaps between platform and train are dangerous.** The meaning is clear. The sign if brief and to the point. It's a warning that doesn't waste words.

A guard might warn a passenger that: **The gaps between the platform and train are dangerous.**

Or that: **The gaps between the platform and the train are dangerous.**

The are all idiomatic. They might be used in different contexts but none is better than the others. Take your pick!